# Android Button Gradient

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create button gradient image as following image . I don't have to use **image** .I have developed it using gradient . Button unable to achieve similar effect in following image.

**Main Image**

http://postimg.org/image/is1cvy09d/

**Developed Image**

http://postimg.org/image/6lojcsayh/

**.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#343434" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#556E6E6E" android:startColor="#55828282" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

You can check result of following image which is too different then above one.

Any idea , how to achieve similar result ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#7A7A7B" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#707070" android:startColor="#848484" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
    </selector>
```